# Getting a Redis command response that was lost due to network error

Tags: redis

If a Redis command is successfully executed, but a network error happens while the response is in transit (preventing the client from receiving it), is there any way of getting the result of that command?

Comment: Add some more specific context about your network setup and the specific network error you experienced.

Comment: Just rephrased this to be a little bit more clear. Unfortunately, I think the answer is that it's not possible unless you have a proxy of some kind in front of Redis.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without a proxy of some kind in front of Redis. Redis `MONITOR` only logs commands, not responses. See https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/150